# how to solve error "The given key was not present in the dictionary." when using data set with MySqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ado.net

I try to make connection with MySQL db  using this class.

```
public class DataManager
{
    // Connection String
    public static string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn1"].ConnectionString; 

    public static DataSet GetDataSet(string stored_name, string table_name, params MySqlParameter[] prmarr)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stored_name,con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (MySqlParameter prm in prmarr)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(ds,table_name);
        return ds;
    }
```

then I called it in load event of page that is inhered from master page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {  
         // product_select is stored procedure/ routine that I made it in db
                using (DataSet ds = DataManager.GetDataSet("product_select","x")) // error is here
                {
                    DataList1.DataSource = ds.Tables["x"];   
                    DataList1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

when I run,I get this error.

```
An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
{"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}
```

my stored procedure in xampp db

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `product_select`()
    NO SQL
SELECT 'P_id','name','unit_price','image_product' FROM product$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What SQL are you finally generating/executing?

Comment: SELECT 'P_id','name','unit_price','image_product' FROM product

Comment: Are you sure that you have a stored procedure with that name? What happens if you don't try to get back the database with its name but just using the index 0?

Comment: And of course the stored procedure uses backticks around the field names  not single quotes right?

Comment: @ Steve yes, I have stored procedure   with same name in xampp db  . and I changed single quotes to backtracks but it is the same error .I believe that my error in data set . and how to get data with index

Comment: _DataList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];_  but your code should work. Can you post the code of the stored procedure?

Comment: You still have single quotes around the fields. This will return all records with three strings with the same value of your field names. Given the fact that these fields are not reserved words you can remove the single quote and there is no need to add backticks to replace the quotes

Comment: thanks Steve  the problem as you say when I use single quote ,this is will return all records with three strings with the same value of your field names  the solution is to remove  single quote .thanks very much.